# With langchain and python, how can I send very big context and separatedly send query?

Tags: nlp, langchain

I'm new to langchain and looking for an expected way of doing the following thing.
I have quite big context data such as a very big table. And the task is question and answer which needs to check that table to generate output.
So, I want to send this big context only once so that all the following request can be very short query.
Here, I'm not sure about two points. First, how can I separate the context and query? Second, for that context sending, how can we make a chunk to send?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To load and split the documents you can use below code

```
    def load_source_documents(folder_path):
        all_documents = []
        dir_loaders = [DirectoryLoader(folder_path, glob="**/*.txt")]
        #print(doc_loaders)
        
        for loader in dir_loaders:
            document = loader.load()
            all_documents.extend(document)

        return all_documents

    def split_documents(documents):
        text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=40)
        chunked_documents = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

        return chunked_documents
```

If you are using any vector store below the example for datalake

```
   def setup_datalake_add_documents(chunked_documents, org_id, dataset_name):
        #embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-ada-002")
        embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
        my_activeloop_org_id = org_id 
        my_activeloop_dataset_name = dataset_name 
        dataset_path = f"hub://{my_activeloop_org_id}/{my_activeloop_dataset_name}"
        db = DeepLake(dataset_path=dataset_path, embedding_function=embeddings)

        # add documents to our Deep Lake dataset
        #db.add_documents(chunked_documents)
        
        return db 

    def query_datalake(db, query, subject):

        filter={"metadata": {"source": f"output\\{subject}.txt"}}  
        #Distance function L2 for Euclidean, L1 for Nuclear, Max l-infinity distance, cos for cosine similarity, dot for dot product
        docs = db.similarity_search(query, filter=filter, distance_metric="cos")

        return docs
```